# Python error with a school assignment, ride time not defined

Tags: python

When I run the code, I'm getting an error that says my ride time is not defined. I'm very new to Python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    if ride_time<=30:
NameError: name 'ride_time' is not defined
```

```py
print(" Menu:\n Enter 1 if you have annual subscription. \n Enter 2 if you have a daily subscription.")

subscription_status = int(input(" Please enter your subscription type: ")) #Storing subscription type

if subscription_status==1 or subscription_status==2:
  print("Welcome to Bike Share!!!!")

  print("Want to know your fare :")

  print("1. Monday\n2.Tuesday\n3.Wednesday\n4.Thursday\n5.Friday\n6.Saturday\n7.Sunday")

now = int(input("Please enter a valid day(in number): "))

pickup_time = int(input("Please enter your pick up time(in minutes) :"))

drop_off_time = int(input("Please enter your drop of time(in minutes) :"))

def calculate_fare(now, ride_time, drop_off_time):

  calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time) 



def calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time): # Calculate_fair function

  ride_time = drop_off_time-pickup_time

if ride_time<=30:

  print("Your fair for journey is 0.")

elif ride_time>30 and ride_time<=60:

  print("Your fair for journey is 1 dollar.")

elif ride_time>60 and ride_time<=120:

  print("Your fair for journey is 3 dollar.")

elif ride_time>120 and ride_time<=600:

  print("Your fair for journey is 7 dollar.")

elif ride_time>600:

  print("Since your riding time exceeds 10 hours. So you need to a fine of 50 dollars")

else:

  print("You eneter something wrong..\nPLease try again..\nThank You")
```

Comment: Hi Tommy, welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question to show the traceback of your exception, as it will identify for us exactly where you're encountering your error. The one odd thing I see in your code is the line `def ride_time = drop_off_time-pickup_time`, which doesn't make any sense (`def` needs a function signature after it, not an assignment). If that's not your issue, it may be an indentation problem, can you double check that the code in the question (as formatted) matches what you're actually running?

Comment: Post the traceback so we can see the error. Also, your code indents aren't right... can you lean up the post so we can get the full picture. Finally, a tip - make a copy of your code and keep cutting it down until you get a small program with the problem. It doesn't need to make sense as a program, just narrowed for the essesitals of the problem.

Comment: Blckknght- I am not sure how to properly define ride_time as a function, or where exactly it should go. I see that I wrote it incorrectly to begin with, trying to fix it but not having much luck

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you define `ride_time = drop_off_time-pickup_time` inside function `calculate_fare` but next line (which makes problem) `if ride_time<=30:` is outside this function. And variable created inside function is local variable and it doesn' exists outside function. I don't know why you define function `calculate_fare` - why don't yo use `ride_time = drop_off_time-pickup_time` without function.

Comment: `ride_time` is defined inside of the `calculate_fare` function, which means it can't be access outside of it, right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop_off_time = int(input("Please enter your drop of time(in minutes) :"))
def calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time): # Calculate_fair function
  return drop_off_time-pickup_time
ride_time = calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time)
if ride_time<=30:
```

You need to remove the **"def"** keyword at the start of the last statement, I assume ride_time is a variable but you are suggesting to the interpreter that it is a function.

Edit1:
Also, calculate_fare() is defined twice which isn't right. You may want to remove the first declaration of calculate_fare() to make the code syntactically correct.

Edit2: You want to return the value of your function calculate_fare(), that way when you call it from your code, the function does the calculation and returns you a result. Then you would want to store the result in a variable, in your case ride_time.

P.S. I would also suggest you follow a tutorial around Python basics and learn about functions, variables, conditional statements like [this](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/compound.html).

Answer (score 0):

You define function

```
def calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time): # Calculate_fair function

  ride_time = drop_off_time-pickup_time
```

which create variable `ride_time` but variables created inside function are local variables and they are not accesible outside function. This way you can use the same name in different functions and variable in one function will not change accidently value in other function.

if you really need to use function then you should use `return` to return value from function and you have to execute this function to calculate and get this value

```
# define function
def calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time): # Calculate_fair function
    result = drop_off_time-pickup_time
    return result

# use function
ride_time = calculate_fare(now,pickup_time,drop_off_time)
```

---

Full code

```
# --- functions ---

def calculate_fare(pickup_time, drop_off_time): # Calculate_fair function
    ride_time = drop_off_time - pickup_time
    return ride_time

# --- main ---

print(" Menu:\n Enter 1 if you have annual subscription. \n Enter 2 if you have a daily subscription.")

subscription_status = int(input(" Please enter your subscription type: ")) #Storing subscription type

if subscription_status == 1 or subscription_status == 2:
    print("Welcome to Bike Share!!!!")
    print("Want to know your fare :")
    print("1. Monday\n2.Tuesday\n3.Wednesday\n4.Thursday\n5.Friday\n6.Saturday\n7.Sunday")

now = int(input("Please enter a valid day(in number): "))
pickup_time = int(input("Please enter your pick up time(in minutes) :"))
drop_off_time = int(input("Please enter your drop of time(in minutes) :"))

ride_time = calculate_fare(now, pickup_time, drop_off_time)

if ride_time <= 30:
  print("Your fair for journey is 0.")
elif 30 < ride_time <= 60:
  print("Your fair for journey is 1 dollar.")
elif 60 < ride_time <= 120:
  print("Your fair for journey is 3 dollar.")
elif 120 < ride_time <= 600:
  print("Your fair for journey is 7 dollar.")
elif ride_time > 600:
  print("Since your riding time exceeds 10 hours. So you need to a fine of 50 dollars")

# this will never executed because other `if/elif` will get all situations
#else:
#  print("You eneter something wrong..\nPLease try again..\nThank You")
```